# need help understand, java: <identifier> expected in the below code

Tags: java

Below is a simple code to find area of the rectangle.
It runs in to compilation error, not sure what is wrong
please help.

I get this error - java:  expected:16

```
public class test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    float l = 7.33f;
    float b = 4.22f;
    Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle( l,b);
    float area = R1.area();
    System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle R1 is " + area);
  }
}
```

```
class Rectangle {
  float l;
  float b;
  public void Rectangle(l,b){
    this.l= l;
    this.b= b;
  }
  public float area(){
    return this.l*this.b;
  }
}
```

Comment: The constructor signature should be `public Rectangle(float l, float b){`.  A constructor doesn't have a return type, not even `void`.  What it _does_ have though is types specified for each of its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor in the Rectangle class is written incorrectly. It should be like below -

```
 class Rectangle {
      float l;
      float b;
      
     public Rectangle(float l, float b){ // need to declare the variable types 
        this.l= l;
        this.b= b;
      }

      public float area(){
        return this.l*this.b;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because of your constructor, `public void Rectangle(l,b)`, you made it like a method
Second, you're missing two `float`s, so:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float l = 7.33f;
        float b = 4.22f;
        Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(l,b);
        float area = R1.area();
        System.out.println("The area of the Rectangle R1 is " + area);
    }
}
 class Rectangle {
    float l;
    float b;
    public Rectangle(float l, float b){//changed here
        this.l= l;
        this.b= b;
    }
    public float area(){
        return this.l*this.b;
    }
```